# Radian of vector perpendicular to vector

Tags: c++, allegro5

I have a vector between `(posX, posY)` and `(mouseX, mouseY)`, and I get the mouse position as a positive integer with allegro's event library. From this vector using an arc tangent I get the radian of `(deltaX, deltaY)`. I then plug that radian into an `al_draw_rotated_bitmap` function. I expect the bitmap to point towards where the mouse cursor is, but the issue I have is that the radian or vector is causing it to be rotated perpendicular to the cursor.

Here is the relevant code:

```
void setRotation(int dx, int dy)
{
    float deltax = posX - mouseX;
    float deltay = posY - mouseY;

    rotation = atan2(deltay, deltax);
}

void Player::draw()
{
    al_draw_rotated_bitmap(player, al_get_bitmap_width(player) / 2, al_get_bitmap_height(player) / 2, posX, posY, rotation, 0);

}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        player.setRotation(mouseX, mouseY);
        player.draw();
        al_flip_display();
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help if you could clarify what inputs you used, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: @JimLewis I just edited the post to include more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine `(deltax, deltay)` = `(0, 100)`, that is the mouse is 100 pixels above the object, and so the picture (I believe) shouldn't be rotated at all. But `atan2(deltay, deltax) = atan2(100, 0) = π/2`, that's why your picture is rotated perpendicularly.

To fix this you should change it to `atan2(deltax, deltay)`, possibly adding `-` before arguments depending on the direction of X and Y axes in Allegro, which I don't know.

In other words, `atan2` measures the angle relative to X axis, but in your case the angle should be measured relative to Y axis (because alignment on Y axis means no rotation), so you should swap its arguments.

Comment: That worked, thanks! It's no longer at a 90 degree angle. But now it rotates counter clockwise as I move the mouse around clockwise and vice versa. EDIT: Nevermind, I just had to make the deltaX negative before the arc tangent.

Comment: Mathematically equivalent : PI/2

Comment: PI/2 - atan2(dy,dx)